# Django unable to render my template because it is unable to find my url. This only happens with url patterns from one of my apps

Tags: python, html, django

Django is unable to load my template because "NoReverseMatch at /books/outlines/20
"

This issue lies within a link in the template:

> ```
>     <a href="{% url 'test'%}" class="type">New Blank Outline</a>
> ```

Here is my outlines/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Dashboard
from . import views as outline_views

urlpatterns = [
 path('<int:pk>/', outlines_views.outline, name='url-outline')
 path('blank/<int:storyPk>', outline_views.newBlankOutline, name='url-blankOutline'),
 path('test/', outline_views.testView, name = 'test')
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Here is the testView:

```
def testView(request):
  return render(request, 'outlines/test.html')
```

Here is the outline view:

```
def outline(request, pk):
context = {
    'storyPk': pk
}
return render(request, 'outlines/outline.html', context)
```

The django error tells me:
NoReverseMatch at /books/outlines/20
Reverse for 'test' not found. 'test' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

The weird thing is, if I change the url name in the template to a url name from another app's urls.py file, it renders the template no problem.  Any idea why it can't find the url?

Comment: Does this `<a href="{% url 'test'%}" class="type">New Blank Outline</a>` work on a different template?

Comment: @Daniel it does not work.  gives me the same NoReverseMatchError

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url 'YOURAPP_NAME:test'%}" class="type">New Blank Outline</a>
```

how about try this